# how to use the same login for wordpress and my flex builder 4.6 desktop app

Tags: sql, apache-flex, actionscript

I am a novice so please help me a bit.

I am using Flex Builder 4.6 to make a desktop app, I want to make people login before they can access the app, I want them to login with the same user info they use on my wordpress site, The database is hosted via godaddy and i have all the phpmyadmin information. I have googled and googled but I am either not doing the right set of words or this isn't possible because I cant find any examples on how to do this.

right now its a blank app with a username and password text input along with a button to login.

Comment: Flex doesn't directly support ODBC database calls -- its data access is done via HTTPService (GET/POST requests), WebService (SOAP), or RemoteObject components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't do this directly and would need to leverage Java (or similar) such as using a server application.

I've never seen or heard of anyone doing this directly via AIR. I suppose it's theoretically possible, albeit not trivial.

Edit:
Thinking about it...this would probably be a kludgy/hacky solution, you could try leveraging Java directly from the users PC by packaging a Java "service utility" with your overall install process, which would interface with your AIR Flex app. They'd need to have Java installed, and additional firewall permissions could be a pain.

You'd need to use [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html).